# Elastic Search 7.9 is taking too much time for indexing than the Elastic Search 1.4.2

Tags: elasticsearch

We want to upgrade our single node ES 1.4.2 cluster to single node ES 7.9 cluster. I was testing performance on both ES versions. I tried adding 100000 documents in one index on both version. It takes 2-3 mins in ES 1.4.2 but it takes 3 hrs for ES 7.9. I am adding same data on both and using same query on both ES versions. I really wonder why after upgrading the performance got decrease, I was expecting increased performance after upgrading. Below is the query I used to add the document to the index.

PUT http://localhost:9200/customer/doc/1?pretty

{
"name": "Customer 1",
"code": "Code 1",
"address": "Address 1",
"phone": "phone 1"
}

Comment: Are the configurations same in both the case in terms of machine, RAM, Shards, size of the index, etc? Can you give some information about your configurations as well

Comment: I have installed both ES 1.4.2 and Es 7.9 on the same host so machine config is same. Index size is same as same data I am trying to write.  ES 1.4.2 elasticsearch.yml is same as provided with default settings except the http.port: 9201 and transport.tcp.port: 9301. elasticsearch.yml for ES 7.9 is  is also  same as provided with default settings. I am adding records/documents by java program.